# Spring terminates context when Quartz jobs are running

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I create Quartz job and start scheduler

```
JobDetail job = newJob(InfoCrawlerJob.class)
                        .withIdentity("job id", "group")
                        .usingJobData(jobData)
                        .build()

                SimpleTrigger trigger = newTrigger()
                        .withIdentity("trigger id", "trigger-group")
                        .startNow()
                        .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
                        .withIntervalInSeconds(100)
                        .withRepeatCount(10))
                        .build()

                scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger)
                scheduler.start()
```

Quartz jobs are working correclty. The main problem is Spring doesn't wait jobs to be finished. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Spring Quartz Support

- [Spring Reference Chapter 25.6 Using the OpenSymphony Quartz Scheduler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html)
- Class [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SchedulerFactoryBean.html)

This class has a method: [setWaitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown(boolean)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SchedulerFactoryBean.html#setWaitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown%28boolean%29) ,  I would expect that this is what you need.

Comment: The solution is working fine, but I saw that the other components (HikaryCP DB) are closed before the job finished, so I can't terminate job regolary. How can I do to prevent this ?